# jQuery: Element offset() coordinates relative to another element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` to drag a `<ul>` element horizontally located inside a `<div>`.

I'd like to get the coordinates of the buttons located inside the `<li>` elements to center them inside `#the_parent`, but the position I get changes every time I resize the browser window, how I can get a position relative to `#the_parent`?

```
<script type:"text/javascript">
    $(document).ready (function () {
        $(".button").click (function () {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            alert (offset.left);
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #dragme li { float:left; list-style:none; }
    #the_parent { width:100%; }
    .spacer { width:100px; }
    .button div { padding:5px; background-color:darkgrey; color:white; }
</style>
<!-- this is contained inside another div of width:600px and it's centered in the middle of the page -->
<div id="the_parent">
    <ul id="dragme">
        <li class="spacer"></li>
        <li id="btn_01" class="button">
            <div>click</div>
        </li>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
        <li id="btn_02" class="button">
            <div>click</div>
        </li>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you want `position()` instead of `offset()`. From the jQuery docs:

> [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/): Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.
>
> [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/): Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.

Comment: thank you, sometimes I should dedicate some minutes to documentations

Comment: @vittorio: Indeed. In fact, the docs for `offset()` even mention `position()` as a related function. :)

Comment: Thanks! In my project the offset was returning sizes > 1,000 and it took me some time to find out why I can't see the elements on the image map.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) not [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).